# nested function does not recognize javascript "this" keyword

Tags: javascript

I can't get my nested function to recognize the "this" keyword.  Here is an example. I have a constructor function:

```
function person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.changeName = changename;
}
```

I have another function with a nested function:

```
function changeName (name) {
     this.lastname = name;
     $.post("display.php", "some_data", function(data,status) {
        if (status=="success") {
               alert(this.lastName); //undefined
        }
     }
```

}

Comment: Not that the usual convention for class names is to have them capitalized (i.e. `Person`, not `person`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function sets this from the inner function you need to either use .bind or the "hack" of that:

```
function changeName (name) {

     var that = this;

     this.lastname = name;
     $.post("display.php", "some_data", function(data,status) {
        if (status=="success") {
               alert(that.lastName); //undefined
        }
     }
}
```

Or by using [function.protoype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
function changeName (name) {

     this.lastname = name;
     $.post("display.php", "some_data", function(data,status) {
        if (status=="success") {
               alert(this.lastName); //undefined
        }
     }.bind(this))
}
```

This is a pretty good [explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: *this* isn't "inherited", it's set by how the function is called.

Comment: @RobG - agreed, poor choice of words.

Comment: Thanks Sten Muchow. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

That's  because `this`, in the event handler, is `window`. You can define an alias in the `changeName` scope like this :

```
function changeName (name) {
     var p = this;
     p.lastname = name;
     $.post("display.php", "some_data", function(data,status) {
        if (status=="success") {
               alert(p.lastName);
        }
     }
}
```